# How to get cards that have been updated recently with Trello API?

Tags: api, trello

I am using the Trello API to get all the cards in a list. I am using the "Since" argument with the date of the last time I got the cards so that I only get cards that have been modified recently:

```
var parameters = {
    filter: 'open',
    fields: 'all',
    checklist: 'all',
    since: self.lastDate
};

var path = '/lists/' + list.id + '/cards/';
Trello.get(path, parameters, getCards, getCardsFailed);
```

The first time I run this I get all the cards and I save the date.
When I run this again with the new date I get no cards. 
If I create a new card and run it again I get the new card. Up to here everything works as it should.
But if I modify a card by changing the name or by adding a checklist item I do not get this card again.

I want to be able to get all cards that have been modified since the last time I read them.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably ask for the actions on that list and filter by updateCard,createCard,copyCard etc so you can get all the actions relating to modifying, adding or removing cards since the last time you checked.

You can then build the list of modified cards from that.

Comment: Thank you Robin, after trying many things, I think this is the only option. I will start working on it. I gave you an up-vote but I don't have enough reputation for it to show.